# Formateo de dataframe python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

Tengo un cojunto de datos de identificacion fiscal de empresas.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

csv =StringIO(u'''\
NIT, TYPE
8600219985, company
9001899451, company
19479647, person
19065171, company
79896134, person
87111760819, person
''')
```

y deseo formatear los registros que coincidan con TYPE = company, para que quede de la siguiente manera:

> ```
>    NIT             TYPE
> 860.021.998-5   company
> 900.189.945-1   company
> 19479647        person
> 190.651.71      company
> 79896134        person
> 87111760819     person
> ```

Alguna idea de como hacer esto con python pandas??

Comment: Yan para aclarar, ¿la idea es dejar como están los que son "person" y los que son "company" parsearlos de una forma u otra en función de si tienen 8 o 10 dígitos? No veo forma de hacer esto que no sea trabajando con una función Python jugando con slicing y unión de cadenas... Si se aplicara a toda la columna se podría hacer durante el parseo del csv, si depende de la columna TYPE como muestras en el ejemplo hay que hacerlo después.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Trabajando con Pandas y expresiones regulares

La idea aquí es la definición de una lista diccionario: `patrones` que va a contener un patrón de expresión regular y una función anónima de reemplazo. Y aplicamos la lista sobre el `dataframe` solo en los casos en que `df['TYPE'] == ' company'`. A nivel de pandas usamos [`str.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas-series-str-replace) para efectuar el reemplazo, por ejemplo si se encuentra el patrón:

`^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{1,2})$`

es decir, desde el principio de la cadena tres grupos de tres números y un grupo de 1 o 2 números más y, si hay coincidencia, obtendremos cada uno de estos grupos por separado y podremos formatearlos así:

`"{0}.{1}.{2}-{3}".format(m.group(1),m.group(2),m.group(3),m.group(4))`

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

csv = StringIO(u'''\
NIT, TYPE
8600219985, company
9001899451, company
19479647, person
19065171, company
79896134, person
87111760819, person
''')

df = pd.read_csv(csv, dtype=str, names=["NIT", "TYPE"], header=0)
patrones = [
              {"patron": r"^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{1,2})$", "repl": lambda m: "{0}.{1}.{2}-{3}".format(m.group(1),m.group(2),m.group(3),m.group(4))},
              {"patron": r"^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})$", "repl": lambda m: "{0}.{1}.{2}".format(m.group(1),m.group(2),m.group(3))}              
  ]

for p in patrones:
  df.loc[df['TYPE'] == ' company', 'NIT'] = df.loc[df['TYPE'] == ' company', 'NIT'].str.replace(p["patron"], p["repl"])

print(df)

             NIT      TYPE
0  860.021.998-5   company
1  900.189.945-1   company
2       19479647    person
3     190.651.71   company
4       79896134    person
5    87111760819    person
```

Answer (score 2):

Podemos escribir una función que reciba una cadena con el número sin formatear y lo devuelva formateado. En este caso, a falta de más información, supongo que la elección del formato depende de si el número tiene 10 cifras o menos:

```
def format_number(n):
  if len(n) == 10:
    return "{}.{}.{}-{}".format(n[0:3], n[3:6], n[6:9], n[9])
  elif len(n)<10:
    return "{}.{}.{}".format(n[0:3], n[3:6], n[6:])
  else:     
    return n    # Resto de casos no sé cómo tratarlos, lo dejo como estaba
```

Ahora podemos aplicar a cada fila una función (lambda) que sustituya el NIT por lo que devuelva la función `format_number`, para las filas en las que TYPE sea "company".

```
csv =StringIO(u'''\
NIT, TYPE
8600219985, company
9001899451, company
19479647, person
19065171, company
79896134, person
87111760819, person
''')

# Leer el csv (corrijo el nombre de las columnas para que no
# contengan espacios indeseados
df = pd.read_csv(csv, dtype=str, names=["NIT", "TYPE"], header=0)

# Aplicar la transformación deseada en la columna NIT
df.NIT = df.apply(lambda x: format_number(x.NIT) if "company" in x.TYPE else x.NIT, axis=1)
```

Resultado:

[image: Dataframe]